# AngularJS: Pass data from from ng-init to <script>

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is how code looks:

```
<div ng-init="companyData">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.timeline = new TL.Timeline('timeline-embed', sampleJson);
  </script>
</div>
```

Is there a way to pass `companyData` in `ng-init` to the `timeline`? I want something like this:

```
<div ng-init="companyData">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.timeline = new TL.Timeline('timeline-embed', {{companyData}});
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you init `new TL.Timeline()` inside your controller. In that way you could parse `$scope.companyData` like `window.timeline = new TL.Timeline('timeline-embed', $scope.companyData);`. Would you accept this as an answer?

Comment: Answer it, I will implement. If it works, I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to init `new TL.Timeline()` inside your controller logic. I try to avoid using `ng-init` because it always ends in to much logic on the "view"-side of your application. Handle that kind of stuff in your controller would be much more tidy.

#### view

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl"></div>
```

#### AngularJS App

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.companyData = 'someData';
    window.timeline = new TL.Timeline('timeline-embed', $scope.companyData);
});
```